# Como separar código PHP do HTML?

Tags: php, html

Boa noite,

E o seguinte eu estou a desenvolver um projecto grande e já estou quase a terminar mas agora vi a necessidade de separar o código por questões de organização da estrutura e maior desempenho pois e uma plataforma que futuramente irá ter um grande volume de trafego  `PHP` do `HTML` qual a melhor forma de  fazer essa alteração em grandes mudanças na plataforma ?

Comment: Usa um Framework MVC

Comment: Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Esta pergunta está um bocado ampla, seria melhor dar mais detalhes do que você precisa fazer. Por exemplo, separar só porque ouviu dizer que é bom, é uma "lenda" (como quase qualquer papo de "boas práticas"). Se você tem um motivo real para fazer isto, coloque as suas necessidades na pergunta e os problemas que está tendo, para que possamos ajudar. Da forma como está, provavelmente esta pergunta atrairá votos para fechamento.

Comment: Existe vários, vai do seu projeto e nivel de exp em php

Comment: Editei e melhorei melhor a pergunta

Comment: Eu não comecei ainda a implementar a funcionalidade perguntei porque preciso de saber um principio por onde começar por isso não detalhei muito coloquei o essencial que preciso dessa funcionalidade

Comment: Você não conseguiria colocar na pergunta um motivo ao menos? Já ajudaria bastante. Separar PHP do HTML não tem muito a ver com o tráfego. Sem mais detalhes, o que dá pra dizer é "faça em PHP as páginas que tem informações que mudam dinamicamente, e em HTML as que tem informações fixas", mas acho que não é bem isso que você quer. De qq forma, vamos ver se aparece alguma coisa que te ajude.